# Start multiple apps running in shells split in one console

Tags: command-line, scripts

I need to start multiple apps running in shells and monitor their execution. Currently I have a main script that launches every apps in a new gnome-console but I would prefer to launch them all in the same window in split screens.

This post [Multiple shells in one window](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31131/multiple-shells-in-one-window) explains how to use split screens with many type of console applications such as screen, terminator and byobu. This works fine manually but I would like to be able to start all my apps in a split screen console automatically from my main scrip. In the documentation from the tools mentioned above there was nothing I could fine to achieve this automatically from a script.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make a custom screen config file that will open up multiple splits and launch your scripts in them. It would look something like this:

```
screen script1.sh # Open first screen and launch first script
split             # Make second split
focus             # Switch to second split
screen script2.sh # Open second screen and launch second script
split             # Make third split
focus             # Switch to third split
screen script3.sh # Open third screen and launch third script
```

Put this in a file called myscripts and launch screen with `screen -c myscripts`. If you prefer vertical splits, just add -v to the split commands.

If you'd like a grid layout, try something like this:

```
screen script1.sh # Open first screen and launch first script
split -v          # Make second split
focus             # Switch to second split
screen script2.sh # Open second screen and launch second script
split             # Make third split
focus             # Switch to third split
screen script3.sh # Open third screen and launch third script
focus             # Cycle back to first split
split             # Split first split horizontally
focus             # Switch to new split
screen script4.sh # Open fourth screen and launch fourth script
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this worked like a charm. The only other issue is that after starting my multiple scripts, I can C-a C-d to return to my terminal but when I do "screen -r" it resumes to my last open tab and I cannot see the output of the other tabs anymore. "screen -ls" shows only one instance but I can see that all my scripts are still running in the process list with "ps". So how can I detach my multi-tab screen and go back to it with the same state?

Comment: I found a superuser question about that: http://superuser.com/questions/69816/how-to-keep-windows-split-after-detaching-reattaching-gnu-screen Looks like a thorny problem. It occurs to me that you might also be able to make a macro that reestablishes your splits.

Comment: The tip from the superuser forum doesn't seems to work for me because the nested session doesn't seem to use my configuration when I launch it with the -c option.

Comment: I also tried your other idea to reestablish my splits with a config file such as the one shown in your answer. But I guess I need to use "screen -r -c macro" but it seems I cannot combine the -r option with -c because it doesn't take my commands into account. "-c" alone re-establishes my splits with empty screens, "-r -c macro" does the exact same thing as "-r" alone and does not create any split.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but it is worth mentioning this tool that does just what you need in an excellent way:

https://github.com/pvolok/mprocs

It runs in one terminal all the needed processes and allow to control them (kill, stop, start, restart).  Ideal for running local servers (flask, expressJS, etc)

Example:

```
mprocs "sleep 5" "sleep 2" vi
```

[image: mprocs running 3 processes]

Comment: Did this tool exist 11 years ago when the question was asked?

Comment: No, they publish the first version on Aug/2021